# How could I create a telegram bot is always running

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I created my telegram bot, and it's running successfully, but I need to keep it running till I closed my PC

Comment: have a look at heroku

Comment: You need to include a bit more information in your question about what you are trying to achieve. The most naive solution to running something indefinitely will be putting it in a `while True` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it on a server. You can deploy it on Heroku for free (https://www.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on your own computer (i.e. not on a server such as AWS or Heroku), you could look to daemonize your application. The easiest would be to use [python-daemon](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/).